# Xcode5: Failed to register "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/MobileDevices.bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cross-platform, xcode5, xcodebuild

My library has some type converters. I'm registering some OSX and iOS type converters, like so:

When I compile for iOS, I'm getting some errors related to not being able to find UIKit. Here's how I compile for iOS:

```
xcodebuild -destination OS=${module.sdk.version},name=iPhone -workspace ${workspace} -scheme '${library.ios.scheme}'
```

*The ${} tokens are patched in by my build system.*

When building I get:

```
__build.library.ios.simulator:
 [exec] Details:  Failed to register "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/MobileDevices.bundle" with Launch Services, error code: -10811.
 [exec] Function: __RegisterUTIsIfNeeded_block_invoke
 [exec] Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7faca140e5c0>{name = (null), num = 1}
 [exec] Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same error messages when using AppCode and Xcode 5 GM, but my apps still compile successfully. This is the single hit on Google for `__RegisterUTIsIfNeeded_block_invoke`!

Comment: You're right: It seems to happen everywhere. . annoying, but not a show-stopper. . I've reworded the question.

Comment: NB: Tag editor: This issue occurs at the compiler level (does not relate specifically to appcode. . marked 'cross-platform' because compiling for both iOS and OSX).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This appears to be an compiler bug, and there's not much that can be done about it.

Here is oficial answer on [JetBrains Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-8201):

*Anton Makeev  17 Sep 2013, 19:36*

> build error doesn't affect compilation results - it's just a log message from xcodebuild.
>   Simulator should work correctly after you run it at least once in Xcode 5.

and:

> We will handle this output in AppCode (show it as a warning, not a n error) but we recommend filing the error to Apple as the message suggests - unfortunately we can't fix it (only hide)

and:

> Build error won't go away until we implement 'hide-it-fix' or until Apple fixes it. It is harmless, though and doesn't affect build result.

Comment: This prevents my unit tests from running on the build server so it may be harmless while compiling but the unit tests dont run as a result.

Comment: This is the error if I run from command line:

2013-09-30 11:46:38.931 xcodebuild[23188:1207] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-3693.1/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDeviceKitBase_Utilities.m:503
Details:  Failed to register "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/MobileDevices.bundle" with Launch Services, error code: -10811.
Function: __RegisterUTIsIfNeeded_block_invoke
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff4a040ed90>{name = (null), num = 1}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

Comment: I'm also having my unit tests fail to run on my build server. Not entirely sure if this error is the cause though.

Comment: I'm also having this issue with my CI builds that run unit tests.  The actual build itself fails codebuild[28837:1007] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-3697/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDeviceKitBase_Utilities.m:503
Details:  Failed to register "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/MobileDevices.bundle" with Launch Services, error code: -10811.
Function: __RegisterUTIsIfNeeded_block_invoke
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe57350deb0>{name = (null), num = 1}

Comment: my Jenkins tests fails also. do you know if it was fixed ?

Comment: This caused my Jenkins test to fail the **first** time only.  The second time I ran the job it passed.

Comment: For me, I had to VNC into my build machine and "Reset Contents and Settings" on the iOS simulator, then quit it. After that the xcodebuild command succeeds every time.

Comment: I did what Drewsmits said with VNC and now everything works like a charm. Before I was pulling my hair out because of this. Thanks!

Comment: I did the same by reseting the simulator, still the issue persists. Could you please suggest as this is blocker for me now to generate uni test case reports