# Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run?

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, xctest

I'm integrating the Jenkins for iOS project and configured the Post-build Actions to "**Publish junit test result report**".

When i run the build using Jenkins I am getting below message not sure where the test report is located.

**Command to execute test case:**

```
xcodebuild -project MyStore2.xcodeproj -scheme MyStore2 -configuration test -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 clean test
```

**Console log:**

```
** TEST SUCCEEDED **

Recording test results
Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run? 
For example, /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Sampletest/workspace/my_app/test-reports/test.xml is 3 min 48 sec old

Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

It may happen when tests report is generated: the new report do not **erase** the old one. How many .xml files do you have in your test-reports folder? Did you try to erase all .xml files in this folder and launch the Jenkins job again?

Comment: There is no report generated under the test-reports folder.i included a test xml file to avoid file not found warning.

Comment: Where are JUnit test result reports generated? Did you configure Jenkins so that it looks in the folder where reports are located?

Comment: Yeah i configured in the post build action to /test-reports/*.xml and created a folder called test-reports as well.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I used _Publish JUnit test result report_ with the following workflow:  1. Erase all JUnit reports located in _/test-reports_ folder  2. Run unit test and generate report in _/test-reports_ folder  3. Configure _Publish JUnit test result report_ to get the report in the correct folder  Are you also using this workflow?

Comment: I guess the issue is due to other 2 blocker issues, if these issues are fixed then the report generation would work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737621/how-to-get-detail-unit-test-case-execution-log-for-ios-in-jenkin-environment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808549/xcode5-failed-to-register-system-library-coreservices-coretypes-bundle-conten