# How to get detail unit test case execution log for iOS in Jenkins environment

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, xctest

While running the Xcode unit test cases through command line I am able to see the below log.

**Command:**

```
xcodebuild -project MyStore2.xcodeproj -scheme MyStore2 -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 clean test
```

**Log:**

```
Test Case '-[MyStore2Tests testIsTrue]' started.
Test Case '-[MyStore2Tests testIsTrue]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Suite 'MyStore2Tests' finished at 2014-07-14 13:01:58 +0000.
Executed 2 tests, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
Test Suite 'MyStore2Tests.xctest' finished at 2014-07-14 13:01:58 +0000.
Executed 2 tests, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
Test Suite 'All tests' finished at 2014-07-14 13:01:58 +0000.
Executed 2 tests, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.002) seconds
```

Where as same when executed through jenkins execute shell the detail log is not displayed it displays the below information.

```
** TEST SUCCEEDED **
```

How to get the detail information of test cases in Jenkins environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is Resolved,

Actually the Jenkins was running in the invisible guest user without having permission to access system resources.
Hence the build was not getting installed in the simulator.

I used the Jenkins app which gets installed as a application in the root.